# Issues with hiding/showing views in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

My app consist of screen with 4 view arranged in table layout of 2 x 2.  Each of them showing videos

[image]

Each view consist of playing controls.  When i presses a button to make a **view3** to full screen the application shows like below.  **View2** overlap to full screen **view3**.  I want only shows **View3** as full screen and avoid **View2**.

[image]

Following code is used to hide/show the views

```
@Override
public void toggleFullScreen() 
{
    mbFullscreen = !mbFullscreen;
    mStrTmp = "";
    Trace((ViewGroup)getRootView(), mbFullscreen);
    mMessage.setText(mStrTmp);
}

private void Trace(ViewGroup layout, boolean bFullScreen ) {
    View FullScreenChild = null;
    ViewGroup FullScreenLayout = null;
    for( int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if( child instanceof MtxVideoView ){
            if( child == this ){
                FullScreenChild = child;
                FullScreenLayout = layout;
            }
            layout.setVisibility(bFullScreen?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
            child.setVisibility(bFullScreen?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            Trace((ViewGroup) child, bFullScreen);
        }
    }

    if(bFullScreen){
        if( FullScreenLayout != null )
            FullScreenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if( FullScreenChild != null ){
            FullScreenChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mStrTmp = mStrTmp + "FullScreen";
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I have amuch simple solution for you. Use FrameLayout to display your selection layout. Add ImageView on top your selection layout but keep it invisible like this  :-**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/select_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/item_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="#000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item 1"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/item_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="#d5d5d5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item 2"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="#d5d5d5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item 3"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/item_4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="#000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item 4"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hidden_imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Result will look like this
[image]

**Now on click of this grid items make hidden Imageview Visible and change image of imageView accordingly**

```
findViewById(R.id.item_1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            findViewById(R.id.select_image).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.hidden_imageView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hidden_imageView))
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.walking);

        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.item_2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            findViewById(R.id.select_image).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.hidden_imageView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hidden_imageView))
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        }
    });
```

...and so on

and to navigate back use tap on imageView like this

```
findViewById(R.id.hidden_imageView).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    findViewById(R.id.select_image).setVisibility(
                            View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.hidden_imageView).setVisibility(
                            View.GONE);

                }
            });
```

[image]

It look nice even if you rotate the screen

[image]

**Hope it will help you .**

Comment: Your solution is nice.  Thanks